# Can I connect multiple USB 2.0 females to a MEAN WELL 5V 10A power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, esp8266, 5v

I have a 5V 10A power supply and some USB 2.0 female breakout boards.
I only need the power and no data.

I have six ESP8266 for small Wled lights which uses a maximum of 1.3 amperes per unit.

I have everything now with USB phone chargers connected but I want to 3D print a USB hub where I can connect all six of them through USB.

Can I just split the wires from the power supply to a WAGO connector and split them to the breakout boards?

Sorry if it’s a noob question.  I tried googling and didn’t find a clear answer.

Comment: Probably not. 1.3 A requires USB handshake/power negotiation.

Comment: @winny - This is only a stupid 5V / 10A power-supply, no communication electronic inside to talk with the USB-device. For the PC there is a 100mA limit and all over this current must be asked for, if you initiate the USB connection.

Comment: @MikroPower I see your point. If the device is dumb and starts pulling 1.3 A without handshake, then yes. Anything USB compliant would not draw anything above 100 mA without negotiation.

Answer (score 3):

You have 10A power-supply and 6x 1.3A = 7.8A of current what you need.
This will work.

Simply connect the USB-sockets with this 5V power-supply, but you should add a fuse to each USB-socket, maybe 1.5A or 2A in case of an error in the LED string. We do not want that it can burn down your house.

Comment: Ah thanks, that sounds clear to me. I’ll have 2 positive and 2 negative outputs on psu, I’ll go from there to a wago connector 2 times. From wago 1 I’ll go to esp 1,2 and 3 with a 2a fuse between each and same for wago 2, to esp 4,5 and 6 if I understand correctly.

Comment: This is okay how you want to do it. Possibly you can use one of this stripe grid board or point grid board for prototyping. The number of positive connections at the power-supply is not important, the positive are connected together and the two GND are connected together too. They are only there to get the 10A over the connectors and one connector would not be enough for this current. Do it like this: +5V from PSU --- 2A Fuse --- 5V-pin at the USB-femal socket. And this 6 times.

Comment: Great! What a great place right here, helpful people that knows what they talk about and explain it very well and “noob” friendly! Thanks all

Comment: Since he wants to power ESP8266, which can also be powered through pins, would it be safer to bypass the USB connection and go through the 5V-GND pins on the board? keeping usb connections in the loop has no advantage and adds another point of failure.

Answer (score 2):

You can. But the thing is, for safety reasons, maybe you should not.

Most standard USB connectors and cables are only rated for standard USB currents - not 10A.

If you ever have an accident and manage to short the ESP supply to ground, or the LED shorts out, the power supply can push 10A through connectors and wiring not intended for 10A.

It can lead into molten connectors and wiring, because there is nothing to limit the current.

At least put some electronics to limit current, or fuses or something to have a safe system.

Comment: Thanks, I will add fuses before each usb line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A USB charger, is just a 5v power supply with a custom connector. Older ones didn't connect anything to the data pins, or just resistors for signaling. Once you get to USB 3, USB c, or PD then you start seeing active signaling and voltage conversion technology.

For you ESP8266 boards, they are *I'm assuming* simple USB 2.0 connections, usb vcc connected directly (or through a diode) to the 5 V pin and to a 3.3 V regulator for the ESP controller itself. The USB data is only used for a USB-serial IC you can ignore. No active signaling of power needs. You can power the board through the 5 V pin instead of needing the USB connector, but I understand its convenience.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and helpful answers.

Comment: @Steve Note that fuses are not fast enough to protect devices from overcurrent. They just stop overcurrent conditions from developing into fires.